# How to write a regex pattern to get rid of unnecessary text?

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I need to get rid of unnecessary symbols and text:

```
{{c1::TEXT TO KEEP}}            –> TEXT TO KEEP
{{c1::TEXT TO KEEP::}}          –> TEXT TO KEEP
{{c1::TEXT TO KEEP::some text}} –> TEXT TO KEEP
{{c1::FIRST TEXT TO KEEP::some text}} SECOND TEXT TO KEEP {{c2::THIRD TEXT TO KEEP::}} –> FIRST TEXT TO KEEP SECOND TEXT TO KEEP THIRD TEXT TO KEEP
```

I wrote this regex pattern: `\{{2}c\d::(.+)(::.*)\}{2}` (replace it with `$1`), but it works only for the second and the third cases, but not for the first one and forth.

How to fix my regex pattern to match all three cases? Could anybody help me?

Comment: You just need to make the first group non-greedy `(.+?)` and the second group optional`(::.*)?`: [`\{{2}c\d::(.+?)(::.*)?\}{2}`](https://regex101.com/r/sWi58c/1)

Comment: @HaoWu Thanks. But a new problem has arisen. If I have two or more strings two keep enclosed in double curly brackets in one line, It keeps only the first string. I assume the whole pattern is greedy, so how to make it not greedy?  
                                                     {{c1::FIRST TEXT TO KEEP::some text}} SECOND TEXT TO KEEP {{c2::THIRD TEXT TO KEEP::}} –> FIRST TEXT TO KEEP SECOND TEXT TO KEEP THIRD TEXT TO KEEP

Comment: I've added an answer based on your feedback, please check if this is the correct behaviour you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make the first group non-greedy `(.+?)` and the second group optional `(::.*)?`.

On top of that, you may want to make sure the second group doesn't consume too much that across the `{{...}}` boundary by adding a negative lookahead: `(::(?:(?!}}).)*)?`

```
\{{2}c\d::(.+?)(::(?:(?!}}).)*)?\}{2}
```

Check the test cases [here](https://regex101.com/r/bImQ7V/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the regex non-greedy by doing `.*?` instead of `.*`. Here would be an example:

- [`{{.*?(TEXT TO KEEP).*?}}`](https://regex101.com/r/Vbryf6/1)

[image]